# How can I wrap long lines without spaces in contenteditable

Tags: css, contenteditable

Hy,
I've tried everything and nothing works.

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kauqdk9j/

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true"></div>

#test { width:400px; height:30px; font-size:13px; border:1px solid #333; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all;white-space: nowrap}
```

I've tried in CSS: word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all;white-space: nowrap, and nothing happens.
Can someone help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 13):

### wrap

```
#test {
    width:400px;
    height:30px;
    font-size:13px;
    border:1px solid #333;

    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

### nowrap

```
#test {
    width:400px;
    height:30px;
    font-size:13px;
    border:1px solid #333;

    word-wrap: normal;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: For wrap, I ended up using `word-wrap: anywhere; overflow-wrap: anywhere; white-space: break-spaces;`.